# Disallow /cgi-bin or not?

Tags: seo

Because of the fact that the rules of **Google** concerning the SEO recently changed, I would like to know if it still advised to disallow `/cgi-bin` or not ?

Thank you in advance,

ArbreMojo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't hurt (except your robots.txt is publicly accessible, anyone can see your directory), but bots who honor the robots.txt file, will skip that directory anyway. If you don't use any CGI scripts, I would simply block it in `.htaccess`.